# Reduce spacing between Bootstrap horizontal form controls

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to remove all the extra spacing between my form controls using Bootstrap 4 horizontal form to make it more compact and smaller. I added the CSS below which removes some of the spacing, but the spacing between label and input is still there, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

```
.form-group {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: Current design showing the space I want to get rid of]

Comment: Add the code to the question

Comment: remove form-horizontal class

Comment: This didn't work. What I want is to remove the space between the label and the input as illustrated in the diagram. The bottom margin on the form group does not affect that between label and input. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding

```
label {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Use `!important` to prevent override:

```
.form-group {
   margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
```

**Or** use bootstrap 4 spacing:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

```
<div class="form-group mb-0">
```

**For example:**

```css
.space .form-group {
 margin-bottom: 0px!important; 
 }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<h1>Without space</h1>
<div class="space">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-grou">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    </div>
<h1>With space</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: While this answer indeed fixed the problem i want to point out that using css `!important` is _never_ good, its always a *workaround*. In general i suggest avoiding `!important` at all cost. Still there are some cases youll need it in some cases e.g. overwriting inline styles from javascript you cant change, but generally speaking a healty approach imo is to stay away as far as you can from !important and just use proper cascading.

Comment: that the reason I added to my answer also `bootstrap 4 spacing` and it spesific to this class also and not all `form-group` in the website

Comment: As said, your answer does indeed fix the problem, i just wanted to add using `!important` is always hacky and never _good_ css code.

Comment: This didn't work. What I want is to remove the space between the label and the input as illustrated in the diagram. The bottom margin on the form group does not affect that between label and input. Thanks

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 spacing there should only be one dash, i.e. _mb-0_

Comment: OMG  i fix it now

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap sets a default `margin-bottom` on the `.form-group` class:

> By default it only applies margin-bottom

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-groups

If youre using precompiled bootstrap just overwrite it using a stronger selector (aka proper [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance)).

If youre compiling bootstrap yourself just set the `$form-group-margin-bottom` variable to whatever value you desire (e.g. `0`).